# R - Modifications on correlation plot (corplot)

Tags: r, plot, correlation

I have 2 questions regarding correlation plots.

Question 1: Can I highlight specific variables in a correlation plot? When I use e.g. the code below and specifically want to highlight the correlations from mpg, cyl, disp and hp on the other remaining variables, can I somehow add a frame around those like in my manually made example?

```
M<-cor(mtcars)
library(corrplot)
corrplot(M, type="lower", order="original", diag=FALSE)
```

[image]
Question 2: Can I make a "correlation plot" containing only the highlighted area? So instead of a 10x10 matrix my plot should only contain the correlations of my selected variables, so a matrix of 7x4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this for the second question :

```
M<-cor(mtcars[,4:11],mtcars[,1:4])
library(corrplot)
corrplot(M, order="original")
```

[image]

I do not think you can answer the first question, but often community surprises with clever solutions.

Comment: Thank you very much!! That was actually way easier than I thought!